# Return a table when a trigger function is called

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I need `some_fun()` to be executed before a trigger. It will return a table.

I ran this:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable(some_bool) VALUES (true);
```

I expected this:

```
 returnColHeader
------------------
12
23
23
(3 row)
```

But I got this:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

I've read documentation on `TRIGGERS` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html
and also `RETURNING CLAUSE` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/dml-returning.html
and a few other `postgres` related readings but I'm still unable to solve my problem.

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS run_some_fun on SomeTable CASCADE;

CREATE TRIGGER run_some_fun
BEFORE INSERT ON SomeTable
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.some_bool = TRUE)
EXECUTE FUNCTION run_some_fun();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION run_some_fun()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT some_fun(NEW.eid); -- This is wrong and throws error
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_fun(eID INT)
RETURNS TABLE (returnColHeader INT) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT eid FROM Joins j1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot to return anything from after trigger. The trigger functions can returns value of composite type, but the returned value from after trigger is ignored. There is not any chance for what you want. And it looks little bit scary.

Comment: But even if I use BEFORE TRIGGER, it doesn't return what i wanted

Comment: @Peter - sure - the method that you use cannot to work ever. But if you use BEFORE trigger, then you can modify content in the table, and you can use RETURNING clause.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if I changed to BEFORE trigger, what else do i need to change?

Comment: @Peter - from row before trigger you can return NEW variable. Next you use `RETURNING clause` in `INSERT` statement. Please, read documentation. It is well described - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question? I need the trigger function to return a table, but the documentation did not mention if its possible. I know that the return type of the trigger function has to be `TRIGGER`, so is there any way for me to get a table?

Comment: @Peter - then reply is simple - trigger cannot to returns table ever. Maybe you can use rules https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-update.html